# Lowpass Butterworth filter equation

Tags: lowpass-filter, bandpass, butterworth, scipy

I am using a 5th order lowpass Butterworth filter with a varying cutoff frequency, $f_c$, to smoothen some data coming from a spectrometer. An example of a spectrum, plotted with the filtered data, looks like this:

[image: Visualised spectrum]

The spectrum thus consists of intensity values over a range of energies.

To apply the filter, I have used the SciPy signal butterworth filter, applied like this:

```
b, a = signal.butter(5, fc, 'low')
self.spec = signal.filtfilt(b, a, self.lowpassdata)
```

where `fc` is the cutoff frequency, and `self.lowpassdata` is an array with the data plotted in orange above. `self.spec` is the resulting filtered dataset.

I have been doing this quite blindly (at least it works) but I would like to know what actually happens, i.e. if the filter follows a specific mathematical function that takes the order, the cutoff frequency, and the spectral data as input.

Thank you!

Comment: If I got your question correct, are you asking how the filter can be applied to the signal?

Comment: I have (blindly) been using the filter to smoothen the spectrum, but I want to know the mathematics that is behind it, as in what the filter actually does. All I know is that it works

Comment: Sara, you're not telling us *how* you've been using the filter on *what kind* of spectral data; please extend your question to explain that – your question can't be answered without.

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks for the hint - I have edited my question, let me know if it makes the question clearer.

Comment: To explain Butterworth filter mathematical details and how it does filtering - I am not sure if someone would be patient enough to answer. Did you search in google before asking it? It is one of the fundamental filters out there so there would be excellent references including wikipedia page. You should be able to follow it if you have knowledge of undergraduate mathematics. Please feel free to ask if you are really stuck though.

Comment: *what actually happens, i.e. if the filter follows a specific mathematical function that takes the order, the cutoff frequency, and the spectral data as input* -- you just described a generic filter, and what happens is [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution).

Comment: You're using a time-domain filter on a frequency spectrum?  That's not an appropriate use of a filter.  It will shift the frequencies to the right from where they should be.  (Oh, you're using filtfilt so the shift is cancelled.  Still, it's a kludgy solution.)

Comment: @endolith A filter is a weighted moving average for any waveform so needn't necessarily be restricted to "time domain". So I personally didn't see this as "kludgy". That said I would never recommend a Butterworth filter, but in general there is nothing wrong with using filtfilt and digital filter implementations to smooth a frequency domain spectrum if you consider it doing just that, right?

Comment: @DanBoschen I guess it's fine if you don't actually care about the information in your spectrum or its accuracy  :D

Comment: Certainly, or you quantify the effect of the processing you are doing. It's similar to video bandwidth adjustment on a spectrum analyzer, with frequency domain processing. (Doesn't reduce noise level but smooths it).